# How do you do Test Driven Development on Mobile Android project?

Tags: android, agile

TDD requires automated testing, so I would like to hear from others how they have applied TDD in Android projects? What worked/did not work well for your team? How did you automate the visual testing in particular?  I can see TDD for the service layer and model but how about TDD and activities, visual changes to layouts etc?

Comment: If it is a product (longer life than 2 years) its worth doing TDD. A small app, life time 3 months its too expensive to do TDD.

Answer (score 3):

The monkey tool, also called UI/Application Exerciser Monkey, can be very useful in the identification of UI bugs and errors. It is a good practice to run it against the apk before any release of an android application.

**How it works**

The Monkey is a command-line tool that you can run on any emulator instance or on a device. It sends a pseudo-random stream of user events into the system, which acts as a stress test on the application software you are developing. To control it you have a list of options.

The options give you control over :

1. basic configuration : number of events
2. constraints : restriction on packages
3. event types and frequencies
4. debugging options

**This is the generic command to run the monkey :**

```
adb shell monkey [options] 

//example
adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500
```

for more information see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) on the officiel android developer website

**Best practices for unit testing Android apps:**

In the  *ApiDemos* sample app, you can find *ActivityUnitTestCase* and *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase* classes.

these are utility classes for testing android programs.

Here are the links to the reference:
[ActivityInstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase.html)
and
[ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html)

*android.jar* includes a subset of **JUnit** test framework for plain old unit test. Take a look at *ApiDemos* sample for learning how to write and run it.

you can try also [Robotium!](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) and [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Spinner/SpinnerTest sample apps in the SDK docs, and also the test project for the Notepad sample app. There's also a Hello, Testing tutorial.

Use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, not ActivityInstrumentationTestCase.

ActivityUnitTestCase has limited value. It runs in a test harness that's not much like the real Android system. AndroidInstrumentationTestCase2 gives you more to work with.

All of the test case classes in android.test are based on Junit3, not Junit4. You can find plenty of documentation on Junit3 online.

The android.test test case classes mimic "unit tests". True unit testing using Junit3 isn't possible in Android for some components such as Activity, because the component class can't be instantiated correctly using reflection alone. The classes such as ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 overcome this with some "magic". I think of them as unit test classes that are very similar to Junit3's TestCase. They're called "functional tests" because unit tests aren't supposed to have external dependencies, and Android activities (for example) need the Android system. I think this is nitpicking, but whatever...

Steps: Start by defining as much as you can in POJOs (Plain Ol' J--- Objects). Test those in unit tests. Test their interaction with functional testing frameworks such as Robotium. Use mocks for anything that isn't an Android object.

From there, use stub Android objects from android.test.mock, and your own stubs, to test Android objects. Finally, when everything else is set up, use the Android test cases to test the "framework".

Mock Android objects aren't easy to implement, which is why the "mocks" in android.test and android.test.mock are really stubs.

Answer (score 1):

To apply TDD for android,  [Android Testing Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#0) will be very helpful to you. Before doing TDD, you need to apply good architectural pattern like MVP, MVVP. So you would be able to extract much more code from your activities and fragments. For activities, visual changes to layouts etc you can check [seventh](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#6) point in code lab. where they have used Espresso to do TDD for Activity and visual layout test. I tried it and it was very helpful to me.

Bonus: Check [Clean Architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/)